# Replace Dataframe column with another dataframe based on conditions - R

Tags: r

i'm with some trouble and maybe someone here can help me!

I´ve a dataframe with three columns( ID1, ID2 and VALUE1). Also i've another dataframe that follows the same configuration but with another values for some ID1 and ID2. I'm trying to replace the values on VALUE1 column in dataframe1 with values that are in the column VALUE1 in dataframe2 only based on multiple conditions. This means, when ID1 and ID2  meet some conditions "x" and "y", then replace those values from dataframe 2.

Below i attach an example. The idea is to use df1 and when ID1=5 and ID2<100, then replace values of VALUE1, from df2. The df3 is the expected outcome( Note that i want to keep all the columns from the df1, just replacing the values when conditions meet)

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1=c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,5), 
                    ID2 = c(10,20,30,40,50,150,200,99,10,25), 
                    VALUE1 = c(100,200,300,400,200, 100,200,40,150,70),
                    NAME = c("Juan", "Rodrigo","Pedro","Lucas","d", "e","f","g","x","a"),
                    SURNAME = c("perez","jones","bla","lopez","martinez","rodriguez","jerez","dieguez","gimenez","mendez"))
     
df2 <- data.frame(ID1=c(5,5,5,5), 
                    ID2 = c(50,150,200,25), 
                    VALUE1 = c(40,30,180,200))
                    
df3 <- data.frame(ID1=c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,4,3,5), 
                    ID2 = c(10,20,30,40,50,150,200,99,10,25), 
                    VALUE1 = c(100,200,300,400,50, 100,200,40,150,200),
                    NAME = c("Juan", "Rodrigo","Pedro","Lucas","d", "e","f","g","x","a"),
                    SURNAME = c("perez","jones","bla","lopez","martinez","rodriguez","jerez","dieguez","gimenez","mendez"))
```

[Example as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKRDk.png)

I tried some things like merge, if, ifelse but i did not reach the outcome. I'm wondering if someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the data in raw format, so I can atleast give it a try :)

Comment: @Mossa  Did it, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID1", "ID2")) %>%
  mutate(VALUE1.x = ifelse(ID1 == 5 & ID2 < 100, VALUE1.y, VALUE1.x)) %>%
  select(-VALUE1.y) %>%
  rename_with(~ sub("\\.x", "", .), contains(".x")) 

   ID1 ID2 VALUE1    NAME   SURNAME
1    1  10    100    Juan     perez
2    2  20    200 Rodrigo     jones
3    3  30    300   Pedro       bla
4    4  40    400   Lucas     lopez
5    5  50     40       d  martinez
6    5 150    100       e rodriguez
7    5 200    200       f     jerez
8    4  99     40       g   dieguez
9    3  10    150       x   gimenez
10   5  25    200       a    mendez
```

Comment: I've another question, if you allow me to abuse your  generosity.  The solution is perfect, but what if i want to replace when the values of df1 are those which are in df2. For example( forget the second condition) if i want to replace the values in df1 with those which are in df2 when id1 is the same., how i could do that? In my first example i put the condition ==5, but i need to do for a diferent values of ID1 that will be part of both dataframes. It seems to be like two vectors checking one to one. I don't know if i am clear enough, but thank you again! @Anoushiravan R

Comment: In this case we used both `ID1` and `ID2` so that we match the exact cases, those that aren't matched will result in `NA`s. So if you want to replace every value1 in df1 with value1 in df2, you just use this `df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c("ID1", "ID2")) %>%
  mutate(VALUE1.x = ifelse(!is.na(VALUE1.y), VALUE1.y, VALUE1.x))`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you again!

Comment: I've some doubts with the last part of the code _"  rename_with(~ sub("\\.x", "", .), contains(".x"))_.  :
1)I understand that it drop all ".x" from the names which have one, how it's working? 2)  I don't know for what is the tilde "~" , 
3)  I Thought that the sub() function needs the df on it third place, and there is just "."  

Again, thanks a lot! I swear this is the last one

Comment: No, it's fine. Yes last line of code actually replaces `.x` with nothing, practically removing that part. `.` here represents `.col` argument which is `contains(".x")` but instead of rewriting it we can put a `.`. The third argument of `sub` is actually a character vector not a data frame, here we are dealing with column names of our data frame most specifically those that contains `.x`.  And ~ (tilde) is a style of coding (purrr style lamba in other word) you can use `function(x) sub("\\.x", "", x)` instead.